# replacing text with a function of that text using regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the text string "[your-name] <[your-email]>" and an Object which contains an array that looks like this

```
  [posted_data] => Array
        (
            [_wpcf7] => 35
            [_wpcf7_version] => 3.5.2
            [_wpcf7_locale] => en_US
            [_wpcf7_unit_tag] => wpcf7-f35-p29-o1
            [_wpnonce] => 2c06b3f0f3
            [your-name] => Andrew
            [your-email] => fr@ibhv.cou
            [your-subject] => plasd
            [your-message] => 11 11 11
            [_wpcf7_is_ajax_call] => 1
        )
```

So what I want to do is write a function that replaces the text in the above string with the values from the object.

So far I have this function

```
function wpcf7ev_get_senders_email_address($wpcf7_form)
{
    //gets the tags
    $senderTags = $wpcf7_form->mail['sender'];

    // replace <contents> with posted_data

    $sendersEmailAddress = preg_replace_callback('/\[(.+?)\]/',
             function ($matches)
             {
                return $wpcf7_form->posted_data[$matches[1]];
             },
             $senderTags
             );

    return $sendersEmailAddress;

}
```

Am I going about this the right way? That callback function fails because the anonymous function doesn't have access to the $wpcf7_form parameter it seems.

I'm using matches[1] as that regular expression returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => [your-name]
    [1] => your-name
)
```

So maybe that could be improved on too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass any dependencies in via the `use` construct, eg

```
function ($matches) use ($wpcf7_form) {
    // etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper class and pass it as callback parameter. This way you could avoid using global parameter.

```
class EmailAddressCallback {
    private $data;

    function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function callback_function($matches) {
        return $this->data->posted_data[$matches[1]];
    }
}

function wpcf7ev_get_senders_email_address($wpcf7_form)
{
    //gets the tags
    $senderTags = $wpcf7_form->mail['sender'];

    // replace <contents> with posted_data

    $callback = new EmailAddressCallback($wpcf7_form);
    $sendersEmailAddress = preg_replace_callback('/\[(.+?)\]/',
             array($callback, 'callback_function'),
             $senderTags
             );

    return $sendersEmailAddress;

}

var_dump(htmlentities(wpcf7ev_get_senders_email_address($wpcf7_form)));
```